# Can't trace the reason for NullPointerException in ContentProvider

Tags: android, database, sqlite, provider

I'm teaching myself the basics of content providers.

I have a contracts class for a ContentProvider called BooksProvder. It's underlying data is in an sqlitedatabase in table called "fiction" with columns, _ID, _TITlE, _AUTHOR and _YEAR.

In the provider's app, I also have:

- DBHelper that extends SQLiteOpenHelper
- BooksProvider that extends ContentProvider
- MainActivity that extends AppCompatActivity which contains no user-defined code, the only UI is the textbox "Hello World" because I'm only interested in the app's contentprovider

In BookProvider:

- I create an instance of DBHelper called dBHelper, this object has a reference (dBHelper.db) to the database in the app's databases directory.
- In provider's query() method I call the database's query method:
  `cursor = dbHelper.db.query(BooksContract.TABLE, null, null, null,null,null,null);`

But the above line throws a NullPointerException when I try to access the provider from a test app, indicating that db is null.  db shouldn't be null because I have located and opened it from the AVD's Device File Explorer. I can't see why it is null. Any help most welcome.

Relevant code is:

Manifest:

```
<application
        
        <provider   android:authorities="com.mo.books_provider_app"
                    android:name=".BooksProvider"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:exported="true">

        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

DBHelper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Context context;

    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, null, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        // Check if database already exists in the app's specific directory
        File f = context.getDatabasePath("Books.db");
        if (f.exists()) {
            db = getWritableDatabase();
        } else {
            AssetCopier assetCopier = new AssetCopier(context, "Books.db", "Books.db");
            try {
                assetCopier.copyFromAssets("Books.db");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // do nothing - there will only be one version (schema of the database)
    }

}
```

Relevant snippet from the BooksProvder class:

```
public class BooksProvider extends ContentProvider {

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    Context context;
    UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        this.context = getContext();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);  // the uri of the whole content provider itself
        uriMatcher.addURI(BooksContract.AUTHORITY, BooksContract.PATH, BooksContract.TABLE_MATCH_CODE);
        uriMatcher.addURI(BooksContract.AUTHORITY, BooksContract.PATH + "/*", BooksContract.ROW_MATCH_CODE);
        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri,
                        @Nullable String[] projection,
                        @Nullable String selection,
                        @Nullable String[] selectionArgs,
                        @Nullable String sortOrder) {

        // query the uri pattern
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {

            case BooksContract.TABLE_MATCH_CODE:  // Return the whole table, all rows, all columns
                cursor = dbHelper.db.query(BooksContract.TABLE,
                        null, null, null,null,null,null);
                break;

                case BooksContract.ROW_MATCH_CODE: // Return a particular row
                    // Extract the row ID (row number from the uri)
                    String bookId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                    cursor = dbHelper.db.query(BooksContract.TABLE, projection, "_ID = ?", new String[] {bookId},
                            null, null, null);
                    break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Unkown URI : + uri");
        }
        return cursor;

    }
```

Comment: You are passing null in place of name of the database inside constructor of dbHelper. From the doc -> name of the database file, or null for an in-memory database

Comment: Add logging to key places of your app and execute this command in the console ```$ adb logcat -s "TAG:*" "*:S"```. It will show you all places called by your app's logic and you can check in runtime if your db has been really initialized.

Comment: db = getWritableDatabase() You should have that line too after copying from assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the books.db does not exist then you do not instantiate **db** and hence it being null and the resultant NPE.

After a successfuly copy of the asset, you then need to instantiate **db** as an SQLiteDatabase, which will require that books.db is opened as an SQLiteDatabase.

So after the asset has been copied then something along the lines of:-

```
  } else {
     // AssetCopier code not supplied in question so mimic the copy
     //AssetCopier assetCopier = new AssetCopier(context, "Books.db", "Books.db");
     // ....
     db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(f.getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE); /* Open the database which now exists (at least should do it AssetCopier did it's business) */
  }
```

When it comes to the file existing then rather than getting the in-memory (i.e. temporary empty database that **IS NOT** the **Books.db**) you probably want to instead use (again)

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(f.getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

instead of

```
db = getWritableDatabase();
```

- sqliteDatabase, due to the **null** for the database name parameter of the super call, will be an in-memory database.
- ensuring that onCreate is always called by using an in-memory database that is not persisted is a novel/unusual way of handling the copy or not of the asset.